# rspec require spec_helper in .rspec file

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

I've noticed that projects such as [bundler](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) do a `require spec_helper` in each [spec file](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/spec/bundler/cli_rspec.rb)

I've also noticed that rspec takes the option `--require`, which allows you to require a file when rspec is bootstrapped. You can also add this to the `.rspec` file, so it is added whenever you run rspec with no arguments.

Are there any disadvantages to using the above method which might explain why projects such as bundler choose to require spec_helper in each spec file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't work on Bundler so I can't speak directly about their practices. Not all projects check-in the `.rspec` file. The reason is this file, generally by current convention, only has personal configuration options for general output / runner preferences. So if you only required `spec_helper` there, others wouldn't load it, causing tests to fail.

Another reason, is not all tests may need the setup performed by `spec_helper`. More recently there have been groups of Rubyists who are trying to move away from loading too many dependencies into the test. By making it explicit when `spec_helper` is required in the test people have an idea what may be going on. Also, running a single test file or directory that doesn't need that setup will be faster.

In reality, if all of your tests are requiring `spec_helper` and you've make it a clear convention on the project there's no technical reason you can't or shouldn't do it. It just may be an initial surprise for new people who join the project.

Answer (score 4):

With a proper setup, there's no downside at all.

The `.rspec` file is meant to be project related (and should be commited like any other project source file).

Meanwhile, the `.rspec-local` is for overriding with personalized settings (and it will let the user override *some* options only).

(see: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files)

Rails projects even use a separate `--require rails_helper` for Rails-specific RSpec settings.

Both the `.rspec` and `--require` options have existed since 2011 at least (which is ages ago).

And, RSpec is *especially* not a tool for people needing training wheels - you want people to understand how RSpec works and what the options are, because you want people to know e.g. when and where to temporarily set the `--seed` option, how to change the formatter, switch on `--fail-fast`, use specific tags to work on a feature, etc.

The test environment also has to have a consistent configuration, so you do not want people tweaking the `spec_helper` file or the `.rspec` file (for the same reason).

In short: if it doesn't apply to *every* spec in the project, it shouldn't be in the `spec_helper` file. Which is why you *should* make sure it *is* included by every spec file. And the `.rspec` file is the best way to do that.

The only reason to not to switch to this is when the project is being actively maintained by many people (and *any* project wide change just creates annoyances by e.g. forcing people to rebase their work for no reason related to what they were working on).

Bundler fits into this category - to many people potentially working concurrently.

P.S. I also recommend using `rspec --init` on an empty project and checking out the generated config.

Comment: I believe you're extracting more meaning from the documentation that you referenced than is actually there. It only talks about the order in which the three .rspec files are loaded, not the intended purpose (project config vs. local config as you call it) or whether or not it should be version controlled. In general, dot files are not meant to be required components of a project and should be used only for personal config. By making a dot file be a shared/required component, you're violating the principle of least surprise. I tend to agree with the accepted answer here.

Comment: @JavidJamae - please read more carefully the descriptions in parentheses. Also, the terms are used as I mentioned: "project", "local" and "global". Note the suggestions as well - is actually *suggests* checking in the `.rspec` file (as opposed to the chosen answer).

Comment: Just in case, I've updated the link to explicitly link to RSpec 3.2 docs (which is what I get by default).